# Remove empty space inside a container and move the container with its content on webpage

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying to remove the empty space inside the container and keep some space around the black box whilst making sure it is responsive.

Also how do I move the container with its content down and to the right of the webpage again making sure it is still responsive?

I have a CSS file and bootstrap 5.

[image]

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-row"></div>
  
  <h1>Image</h1>
  
  <form action="/s">
    <img src=“rectangle.jpg" alt=“black rectangle>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js " integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p " crossorigin="anonymous "></script>
```

Comment: Please, read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: Did you try `width: fit-content;` on `.container`?

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` in your alt for your `img`.

Comment: Thank you soo much @vee. That's worked perfectly. What about the second part of my question. How do I move the container with its content down and to the right of the webpage again making sure it is still responsive?

Comment: I've found a solution to the second part of my question put the following into the `.container` `top: 125px;`

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Solutions don't belong in comments. Also, you have invalid quotation marks in your HTML (and are missing some). Don't work in word processors or copy from them.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `width: fit-content;` to "*remove the empty space inside the container*" and adding `top: 125px;` to "*move the container with its content down*".

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  top: 125px;
}
```